# get image not found 404, API laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, ionic4

I configure an API in Laravel 5.8, is it returns me the data in format JSON when I try to display in Ionic, only the text to be displayed and not the images, what should I do to get the images displayed?

**here is my Laravel controller**

[image]

**and here is my API route**

[image]

**and also the laravel directory which contains the images**

[image]

**and here is my ts service in ionic 4**

[image]

**and here is the result in console**

[image]

If someone can help me find the solution, how to display my images, my recorded images in repeaters and the name in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Images are static files. These files must be web-accessible. You can not access them with `api`.

This will be accessed through URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/2090830955.jpg
```

You are getting `image` in `student` object, so you can define one constant `IMAGE_URL` which will have value `http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/` in your frontend and you can display image like this:

```
<img scr={{IMAGE_URL+student.image}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I extend the answer of `@akshaypjoshi`. He's right with the statement that your way how you access the images would no work. But unfortunatly the example url is wrong.

Everything inside of the laravel public folder is web-accessible and it's the entrypoint for every request. Because of that you don't need to add the `public` folder in your url. So in your case this would look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/structure#the-public-directory) you can read more about the laravel directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @akshaypjoshi.
and thanks also to thmspl, so I understood a little error on my part, I accessed from API instead of going directly...